# Email link in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

I'm implementing a Confirmation after registering system, and the code is working fine, there's a small problem. The problem is that user must click on link but this is how it appears on the below picture.

**Picture email:**

[image]

I actually don't know where am I missing it wrong because I want the link to appear properly and not show generated tokens. If you can check on the first "link" it's not clickable and secondly the other link reveals everything.

**IdentityConfig**

```
  void sendMail(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        #region formatter
        string text = string.Format("Please click on this link to {0}: {1}", message.Subject, message.Body);
        string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\'" + message.Body + "\'>link</a><br/>";

        html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"Or click on the copy the following link on the browser:" + message.Body);
        #endregion

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString());
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Body = message.Body;
        msg.Subject = message.Subject;
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Send(msg);

    }
```

**Account Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Name = model.Name, Address = model.Address, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //Assign Role to user Here
                await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.RoleName);
                //Ends Here 

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);


                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");


                if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "User"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shop");
                }

                if (UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }

                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shop");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to be encoding the html?

Comment: Encoding the HTML will transform `<` to `&lt;` which will then get rendered as `<` in the email application and seen as text instead of HTML

Comment: I need to hide this long link and make proper @johnny5

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it like this.

```
var callbackUrl= Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code });
var link = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, callbackUrl);
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", " " + link + "");
```